# dealing with javascript scoping using inline functions

Tags: javascript, scoping

Because I'm used to C and Java, I've found Javascript's lack of block scope a little irksome. Sometimes I find myself wanting to declare and then immediately execute an inline function just to overcome this issue. For example:

```
... 

if (x == 0) { 
  (function () {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      ...
    }
  })();
}

...
```

Otherwise, I feel the need to declare all of the variables for a function at the top of the scope, in order to avoid forgetting about the lack of block scope. But having a huge var statement at the beginning of a function looks clumsy to me.

The way I've shown above feels wasteful, but I don't have any idea of what it costs to declare inline functions in the first place. Is doing it this way a bad idea? Is there a better way to solve my qualm with Javascript's scoping?

Comment: Defining functions inside `if` clauses is a serious anti-pattern. and I *think* it's illegal in "strict" mode.

Comment: It's an issue because you don't like var blocks-but in JavaScript, there are var blocks. Of course, if your methods are appropriately sized, you won't have many anyway.

Comment: @Pointy: IIFEs aren't that big a deal.  It's the function *statements* that are a problem.  This code may well be illegal, though, since it doesn't have the definition in parentheses (which makes it a statement).

Comment: _"Is there a better way to solve my qualm with Javascript's scoping?"_ Yes, just get over it. You might enjoy the movie titled "Dr. Brendan or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Function Scoping."

Comment: @cHao yes I should have said "declaring functions"; that's a syntax error anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with writing it as follows:

```
if (x === 0) { // you should always use === over == in JavaScript
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // body
    }
}
```

Just because JavaScript doesn't support block scoping doesn't mean that you can't declare variables in block scopes.

**You can declare variables anywhere.** However they'll be visible everywhere in the scope of the function.

The only problem caused by the lack of block scoping in JavaScript is when you define a function inside a loop which accesses free variables (the infamous loop problem).

Read the following StackOverflow thread to wrap your head around it: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/783743)

JavaScript is simple. **Way more simple than C or Java.** It's a lot more sensible than Java too. Java is a pathetic language.

If you want the JavaScript community to be daggers against you then you're doing a wonderful job. Otherwise just [embrace JavaScript](http://www.embracejs.com/). In the words of Douglas Crockford:

> In my own practice, I have found that working with JavaScript has made me a better Java programmer because it introduced me to a useful set of dynamic techniques.

Source: [A Survey of the JavaScript Programming Language](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript scoping, short of ES5 features, is at the function level. It's like how C used to require you to declare variables before anything else; you just have to live with it.

Your code is not syntactically correct. You've got a statement that starts with the `function` keyword, but no function name; it's also followed by `()`. I assumed you're talking about a function declaration statement. If you're just instantiating a function as part of an expression, then scope doesn't really figure into that, at least external to the function.